# Edit CSV file in python which reads values from another json file in python

Tags: python, json, csv

I wanted to edit a csv file which reads the value from one of my another json file in python 2.7
my csv is : a.csv

```
a,b,c,d
,10,12,14
,11,14,15
```

my json file is a.json

```
{"a":20}
```

i want my where the column 'a' will try to match in json file. if their is a match. it should copy that value from json and paste it to my csv file and the final output of my csv file should be looks like this.

```
a,b,c,d
20,10,12,14
20,11,14,15
```

Till now I what I have tried is

```
 fileCSV = open('a.csv', 'a')

 fileJSON = open('a.json', 'r')
 jsonData = fileJSON.json()

 for k in range(jsonData):
     for i in csvRow:
        for j in jsonData.keys():
            if i == j:
               if self.count == 0:

                  self.data = jsonData[j]
                  self.count = 1
               else:

                  self.data = self.data + "," + jsonData[j]         

    self.count = 0
    fileCSV.write(self.data)
    fileCSV.write("\n")
    k += 1 
fileCSV.close()           
print("File created successfully")
```

I will be really thankful if anyone can help me for this.
please ignore any syntactical and indentation error.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you already know how to load JSON, open and read a csv file and manipulate strings? If yes, what's the problem? If no, why did you not find out?

Comment: What have tried so far? Please show some code!

Comment: Cook up a working example (perhaps use `StringIO` instead of files to make it a single file example) so we can see where you are at. We usually don't write code whole-cloth around here. Its best if we can see where you are at and tweak as needed.

Comment: i was posting the code which i tried till now.. but stackoverflow and the community response is very fast that before posting it, I got response. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some basic string parsing will get you here.. I wrote a script which works for the simple scenario which you refer to.

check if this solves your problem:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


def list_to_csv(listdat):
    csv = ""
    for val in listdat:
        csv = csv+","+str(val)
    return csv[1:]

lines = []
csvfile = "csvfile.csv"
outcsvfile = "outcsvfile.csv"
jsonfile = "jsonfile.json"

with open(csvfile, encoding='UTF-8') as a_file:
        for line in a_file:
            lines.append(line.strip())

columns = lines[0].split(",")
data = lines[1:]

whole_data = []
for row in data:
    fields = row.split(",")
    i = 0
    rowData = OrderedDict()
    for column in columns:
        rowData[columns[i]] = fields[i]
        i += 1
    whole_data.append(rowData)

with open(jsonfile) as json_file:
    jsondata = json.load(json_file)

keys = list(jsondata.keys())

for key in keys:
    value = jsondata[key]
    for each_row in whole_data:
        each_row[key] = value

with open(outcsvfile, mode='w', encoding='UTF-8') as b_file:
    b_file.write(list_to_csv(columns)+'\n')
    for row_data in whole_data:
        row_list = []
        for ecolumn in columns:
            row_list.append(row_data.get(ecolumn))
        b_file.write(list_to_csv(row_list)+'\n')
```

CSV output is not written to the source file but to a different file. 
The output file is also always truncated and written, hence the 'w' mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) classes which will read into and out of python dicts. This would make it easier to modify the dict values that you read in from the JSON file.